# ObstacleLayer parameters - where to set them?

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I'm trying to migrate my `costmap_2d` setup to ROS Hydro which involves configuring layer plugins. Loading the plugins is working so far. But the ObstacleLayer that I use in my local costmap won't subscribe to a observation source topic that is configured in another YAML file.

This is how I've configured my `move_base` (launch file):

```
<node pkg="move_base" name="MoveBase" type="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS" />
    <param name="controller_frequency" type="double" value="5.0" />
</node>
```

Here's the part of the costmap_common_params.yaml with the configured observation source `ir_sensors`:

```
ir_sensors: {
  sensor_frame: 'base_link',
  data_type: PointCloud,
  topic: '/ir_sensors',
  marking: true,
  clearing: true,
  obstacle_range: 0.8,
  raytrace_range: 0.8,
  expected_update_rate: 15,
}
```

And here's the configuration of my local costmap (local_costmap_params.yaml):

```
local_costmap:
  robot_base_frame: 'base_link'
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3
  height: 2
  resolution: 0.05
  plugins:
   -
     name: footprint
     type: "costmap_2d::FootprintLayer"
   - 
     name: obstacles
     type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
     observation_sources: ir_sensors
   - 
     name: inflater
     type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
```

The plugins load but the ObstacleLayer doesn't subscribe to the /ir_sensors topic. It looks like it can't find the observation source setup. I've got a strong feeling that it's some namespace related issue. But I haven't figured out yet how to configure it properly.

Thanks in advance for helping me again!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80501/obstaclelayer-parameters---where-to-set-them?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Obstacles layer uses the layer-specific namespace to look for additional parameters. Try this:

```
<rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap/obstacles" />
<rosparam file="$(find otter4_tf)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap/obstacles" />
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-20**:
I've already sort of figured out that by myself (thanks anyway!) but somehow put the cart before the horse. I'm still using ns="local_costmap" and ns="global_costmap" but combined with "obstacle/observation_sources:" inside the corresponding yaml file. Works like a charm.